# How to return a numpy array of the indices of the first element in each row of a numpy array with a given value?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array of shape (2, 4):

```
input = np.array([[False, True, False, True], [False, False, True, True]])
```

I want to return an array of shape (N,) where each element of the array is the index of the first True value:

```
expected = np.array([1, 2])
```

Is there an easy way to do this using numpy functions and without resorting to standard loops?

Comment: Try `np.argmax`

Comment: @hpaulj, what would the call to argmax look like in this case then using input?

Answer (score 1):

`np.max` with `axis` finds the max along the dimension; `argmax` finds the first max index:

```
In [42]: arr = np.array([[False, True, False, True], [False, False, True, True]])
In [43]: np.argmax(arr, axis=1)
Out[43]: array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
nonzeros = np.nonzero(input)
u, indices = np.unique(nonzeros[0], return_index=True)
expected = nonzeros[1][indices]
```